# Freeswitch configuration to make a call h323 to h323 using opal?

Tags: freeswitch, h.323, opalvoip

I am newly working on the freeswitch..
please  help how to make call h323 ->FS -> h323.

I am trying so much but h323 call not established.

I am trying h323 call using opal with freesswitch.

some links that already I followed.
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_h323
https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_opal

Please help me.
how i can eastablish the h323 calls.
please someone guide me..
And which softphone is best for h323 calls.??

please i am waiting someone give me some hints to how i can do it..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to send calls to H.323 endpoints is to assign a certain prefix to them and use that in the dialplan.

I usually use a [GNU Gatekeeper](http://www.gnugk.org/) that registers to FreeSwitch and let all endpoints register to the gatekepeer instead of directly to FreeSwitch. That takes care of all H.323 NAT issues.

Polycom makes some good, inexpensive H.323 softphones (m100 or RealPresence). If you need a free softphone, your only choice is [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/), but its not quiet as good.

BTW: I prefer mod_h323 over mod_opal.

Comment: Thank's for reply...kk will try through GNUgk

Comment: Actually Freeswitch also work as gatekepeer, you have any simillar idea about freeswitch then we can configure h323 calls on freeswitch,without using any external gatekeeper..????

Comment: Freeswitch can act as a gatekeeper, but it is lacking many features, eg. support for NAT traversal. In principle the dialplan works the same if you use an external gatekeeeper or not.

Comment: Hello .. i m trying to much but i am getting error in installing openh323gk.......please help how to solve these error .?
/root/ptlib/src/ptclib/pxml.cxx:149: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/root/ptlib-v2.10.9/make/common.mak:177: recipe for target 'obj_linux_x86_64_s/gnugk' failed
make[1]: *** [obj_linux_x86_64_s/gnugk] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/openh323gk'
/root/ptlib-v2.10.9/make/common.mak:295: recipe for target 'optnoshared' failed
make: *** [optnoshared] Error 2
root@debian:~/openh323gk# 
please give a answer..??

Comment: Hiee..i want gnu gatekeeper integrate with freeswitch..how i can do..?? please give some information about that..??

Comment: Try the GnuGk manual (chapter 14) http://www.gnugk.org/gnugk-manual.html or subscribe to the GnuGk mailinglist (https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/openh323gk-users).

Comment: Hello Gene, Thank you so much for valuable guideline .. we done h323 call on free switch